# Can I start Debian on a text virtual console in a virtual machine?

Tags: debian, kvm, virt-manager, virtual-consoles

I have created a Debian virtual machine in virt-manager/KVM/QEMU.

When I run the Debian virtual machine, I don't really need the desktop environment, which is also resource consuming. Can I start Debian only on a text virtual console (e.g. like ctrl-alt-f1) instead of the graphical virtual console (i.e. ctrl-alt-f7) on the virtual machine?

Thanks.

Comment: And maybe, you should have installed Debian using a Netinstall ISO, that has the essential minimal for a Non-X setup - https://www.debian.org/distrib/netinst - Also, remember to not select a desktop environment during the setup process, or it will download it. Keep up the bare minimal, and the ssh server if you want...

Comment: You could also not give a virtual graphics card at all to your VM and have the console on serial. Like for a physical server, that makes it easier to operate the VM as you can then more easily copy-paste text when you access that console from a terminal emulator on the host.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks. How shall I not give a virtual graphics card at all to your VM and have the console on serial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to switch from the `graphical.target` to `multi-user.target`:

```
systemctl set-default multi-user.target
reboot
```

then use the `chvt` to switch between tty.

---

If debian already up , you can use the `virsh send-key` command from the host machine to switch to the tty.

e,g: to switch to tty2 use the following command:

```
virsh send-key guest --codeset linux  KEY_LEFTCTRL KEY_LEFTALT KEY_F2
```

( `guest` is the VM Name use `virsh list --all` to get the exact name)

**Edit**

To switch to the GUI from the default multi-user target:

```
systemctl start graphical.target
```

You should start the graphical target then you will be able to send <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+F7</kbd> from the host.

Comment: Thanks. (1) With `multi-user.target`, can I switch to GUI? Sending ctrl-alt-f7 from host by  `virsh send-key guest --codeset linux  KEY_LEFTCTRL KEY_LEFTALT KEY_F7` doesn't seem to work. (2) With `graphical.target`, if I switch to a text virtual console from GUI console by ctrl-alt-f1,  can I kill the GUI processes?

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways of going about this, but in your case, I think the best one is to remove the display manager and anything which depends on it, for example

```
sudo apt purge lightdm
```

Next time you set up a VM, if you don’t want a graphical environment, you can [skip installing it altogether](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/508274/86440).

Comment: Thanks. Why uninstall lightdm, instead of Xorg?

Comment: Because removing the display manager is sufficient to get Debian to start on a text VC, which is what you asked for in your question.

Comment: If I uninstall Xorg, which virtual console will it ends up with? Will Debian still start the display manager which then forks other processes, regardless of whether Xorg is installed or not?

Comment: Well, have you tried it? The answer depends on the display manager. Just uninstall the display manager.