# How can I not give a virtual graphics card at all to your VM and have the console on serial?

Tags: kvm, qemu, virt-manager, virsh

Stéphane Chazelas wrote that [Can I start Debian on a text virtual console in a virtual machine?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/509105/can-i-start-debian-on-a-text-virtual-console-in-a-virtual-machine#comment941430_509105)

> You could also not give a virtual graphics card at all to your VM and
>   have the console on serial. Like for a physical server, that makes it
>   easier to operate the VM as you can then more easily copy-paste text
>   when you access that console from a terminal emulator on the host.

In **both** `virsh` and `virt-manager`, how can I:

- not give a virtual graphics card at all to both a to-be-created VM and an existing VM (created in any way, either by virsh or virt-manager), and
- have the console on serial, and
- access that console from a terminal emulator on the host?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing Console Of Ubuntu 16.04 KVM Guest](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/288344/accessing-console-of-ubuntu-16-04-kvm-guest)

Comment: `virt-builder` creates preconfigured VMs with the serial console already enabled.

Answer (score 5):

When I build a new VM, I use the `virt-install` command.  Effectively the command I end up with is something like:

```
$ virt-install \
-n $machine_name \
-r $ram_size \
--vcpus=1 \
--os-variant=rhel7 \
--accelerate \
-v \
--network=bridge=br0 \
--disk path=$destfile,size=$disksize \
-l $repo \
--nographics \
-x "ks=http://10.20.30.40/CentOS/kickstart/centos7.cfg ksdevice=eth0 ip=dhcp console=ttyS0,9600 cmdline"
```

This is for a CentOS7 build and points to my internal source server (10.20.30.40) to pick up the kickstart file.  The `--nographics` tells `virt-build` to not add a graphics card, and the `console=ttyS0,9600 cmdline` tells the installer to work via serial.

Once the machine has been built and is running then I can do `virsh console $machinename` to get to the serial console, eg.:

```
$ virsh console hass
Connected to domain hass
Escape character is ^]

CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
Kernel 3.10.0-957.10.1.el7.x86_64 on an x86_64

hass login:
```